# Uniqueness of the universal covering space (up to an isomorphism)

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$ be universal covering spaces of some topological space $X$. I want to show that $Y_1$ are $Y_2$ are isomorphic.

Denote $p_1 \colon Y_1 \to X$, $p_2 \colon Y_2 \to X$ the projections. Then there exist maps $f_1 \colon Y_1 \to Y_2$ and $f_2 \colon Y_2 \to Y_1$ such that $p_2 f_1 = p_1$, $p_1 f_2 = p_2$. Taking compositions we obtain 
$$
   p_1 f_2 f_1 = p_1, \\
   p_2 f_1 f_2 = p_2.
$$
We have to show that $f_2 f_1 = \mathrm{id}_{Y_1}$ and $f_1 f_2 = \mathrm{id}_{Y_2}$. Suppose that this doesn't hold, i.e. there exists $y_1 \in Y_1$ such that $f_2 f_1 (y_1) = \widetilde y_1 \neq y_1$. This implies $p_1(\widetilde y_1) = p_1(y_1)$. But I don't see a contradiction. Please help me to finish the proof.

Comment: The uniqueness is only for fixed "base points". Fix $x_0\in X$, and $y_1\in Y_1$, $y_2\in Y_2$ with $p_1(y_1) = x_0 = p_2(y_2)$. Then there are unique $f_1\colon Y_1\to Y_2$ and $f_2\colon Y_2 \to Y_1$ with $f_1(y_1) = y_2$, $f_2(y_2)=y_1$ and $p_1\circ f_2 = p_2,\, p_2\circ f_1 = p_1$. Without fixing base points, the relevant concept is "deck transformations".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, thanks. I'll drop the word "unique"

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry, It is vague to me that why without "base points" uniqueness  is meaningless!  For example, let $X=\Bbb S^1$ and $Y_1:=Helix$ and $Y_2:=Helix+z_0$. What is the wrong with this example?

Comment: @C.F.G That referred to the [first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1024141/1) where uniqueness of $f_1$ and $f_2$ was stated. Without base points there are (usually) several such $f_k$, composing such maps with deck transformations yields a different pair of such maps. You get uniqueness (assuming $X$ is connected) if you require that the maps preserve base points.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the spaces with base points $(Y_1, y_1)$ and $(Y_2,y_2)$, notice that $f_2f_1$ is a lift of $p_1$ to the covering $Y_1$ with $f_2f_1(y_1) = y_1$. But the identity map $id_{Y_1}$ is also a lift of $p_1$ with $id(y_1)=y_1$. By uniqueness, we have $f_2f_1 = id_{Y_1}$.

The same argument shows that $f_1f_2 = id_{Y_2}$.

Comment: In the language of category theory, this proof is simply an example of "colimits are unique up to unique isomorphism": Let $(X,x)$ be a topological space with base point $x$. Consider the category of coverings of $(X,x)$ that fix the base point. The objects are covering maps $p\colon (Y,y)\rightarrow (X,x)$ with $p(y)=x$. The morphisms are fiber-preserving continuous maps respecting the base point. Now, a universal cover of $(X,x)$ is simply an intial object in this category. Inital objects (more generally colimits) are unique up to unique isomorphism.